# How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Let's say we have a class:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired private AnotherBean anotherBean;
}
```

Then we created an object of this class (or some other framework have created the instance of this class).

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

Is it possible to still inject the dependencies? Something like:

```
applicationContext.injectDependencies(obj);
```

(I think Google Guice has something like this)

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You can do this using the `autowireBean()` method of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`. You pass it an arbitrary object, and Spring will treat it like something it created itself, and will apply the various autowiring bits and pieces.

To get hold of the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`, just autowire that:

```
private @Autowired AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

public void doStuff() {
   MyBean obj = new MyBean();
   beanFactory.autowireBean(obj);
   // obj will now have its dependencies autowired.
}
```

Comment: Good answer (+1). There's also a second method where you can influence how the autowiring happens: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBeanProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20boolean%29

Comment: But what if I have two objects, and first autowires second. How autowire bean factory deals with dependencies in the case?

Comment: This is actually a bad pattern. If this is how you really use MyBean why not just have constructor with AnotherBean as parameter. Something like:        `code` private @Autowired AnotherBean bean; public void doStuff() { MyBean obj = new MyBean(bean); } `code`. Seems to be like with all these annotations people get really confused and just don't use the basic pattern that were in java SDK since day 1. :(

Comment: I agree - Spring has redefined the entire language.  Now we use interfaces as concrete classes, methods as class instances and all manner of complicated and code heavy methods of doing what you used to do with new and a decent design.

Comment: @Denis if MyBean has dependencies that the actual class don't need, you're registering dependencies that doesn't actually exist, just to instance a class, so there's really no difference.

Comment: I think the answer by @glaz666 is much cleaner/better than this. The only disadvantage of using `@Configurable` I can see is that it requires Spring to use AspectJ under the covers.

Comment: It is a very useful capability and the answer is quite correct. Some frameworks , like struts 2, use this feature to `autowire` their beans. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706221/struts-2-and-spring-how-struts-created-objects-handled

Comment: actually there has nothing mentioned about this in spring framework reference documentation, why is that

Comment: There is also another very helpful `BeanFactory` method that does NOT autowire the bean as such (i.e. it does not inject dependencies by means of setter or field injection), but it does make the bean aware of its surroundings by injecting application context, reference to a bean factory, invoking post-initialization callbacks, and assigning bean a name. And it does not require a `BeanDefinition` to be present (something that autowire() method expects):

`initializeBean(Object existingBean, String beanName)`

Answer (score 18):

You can also mark your MyClass with @Configurable annotation:

```
@Configurable
public class MyClass {
   @Autowired private AnotherClass instance
}
```

Then at creation time it will automatically inject its dependencies. You also should have `<context:spring-configured/>` in your application context xml.

Comment: Galz666, your method looks much cleaner for what I want to do. However I cannot get it to work. I have no xml file and am using entirely Java config. Is there an equivalent to `<context:spring-configured/>` ?

Comment: This is clean solution, but requires a little more effort: You should either use load-time weaving as iimuhin shows above or add AspectJ compiler to project. Load-time as the name suggest will cause additional cost at run-time.

Answer (score 7):

Just got the same need and in my case it was already the logic inside non Spring manageable java class which had access to `ApplicationContext`. Inspired by scaffman.
Solved by:

```
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
factory.autowireBean(manuallyCreatedInstance);
```

Answer (score 6):

I used a different approach.  I had spring loaded beans that I wanted to call from my extended classes of a third-party library that created its own threads.

I used approach I found here https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Super+simple+approach+to+accessing+Spring+beans+from+non-Spring+managed+classes+and+POJOs

In the non-managed class:

```
{
    [...]
    SomeBean bc = (SomeBean) SpringContext.getBean(SomeBean.class);

    [...]
    bc.someMethod(...)
}
```

And then as a helper class in the main application:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass)
    {   
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException
    {   
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me after going to the confluence link. Have upvoted it.

Comment: This work for me thanks. If you are in my country. i am glad to treat you beer

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to share my solution that follows the `@Configurable` approach as `briefly` mentioned in @glaz666 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3979179/1225551) because

- The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813725/1225551) by @skaffman is nearly 10 years old, and that does not mean not good enough or does not work
- The answer by @glaz666 is brief and didn't really help me solve my problem but, did point me in the right direction

### My setup

1. Spring Boot 2.0.3 with `Spring Neo4j & Aop starts` (which is irrelevant anyway)
2. Instantiate a bean when `Spring Boot` is ready using `@Configurable` approach (using `ApplicationRunner`)
3. Gradle & Eclipse

### Steps

I needed to follow the steps below in order to get it working

1. The `@Configurable(preConstruction = true, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE, dependencyCheck = false)` to be placed on top of your `Bean` that is to be manually instantiated. In my case the `Bean` that is to be manually instantiated have `@Autowired` services hence, the props to above annotation.
2. Annotate the Spring Boot's main `XXXApplicaiton.java` (or the file that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) with the `@EnableSpringConfigured` and `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)`
3. Add the dependencies in your build file (i.e. build.gradle or pom.xml depending on which one you use) `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')` and `compile('org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.0.7.RELEASE')`
4. New+up your `Bean` that is annotated with `@Configurable` anywhere and its dependencies should be autowired.

*In regards to point #3 above, I am aware that the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop` transitively pulls the `spring-aop` (as shown here [mavencentral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.0.3.RELEASE)) but, in my case the Eclipse failed to resolve the `@EnableSpringConfigured` annotations hence, why I explicitly added the `spring-aop` dependency in addition to the starter. Should you face the same issue, just declare the dependency or go on adventure of figuring out

- Is there a version conflict
- Why the `org.springframework.context.annotation.aspect.*` is not available
- Is your IDE setup properly
- Etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

See more information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the following way useful for my use case. Sharing here for reference, credit goes to the blogger entirely. This creates a static field and populates that from Spring and then provides a public static method which returns the field populated above.

https://sultanov.dev/blog/access-spring-beans-from-unmanaged-objects/