# Can we configure Spring to configure a property based on the scope of the request?

Tags: spring, https

Can I configure Spring in such a way that I add a property, "isHttps" to the request, and this property can be accessed from anywhere in the code, e.g. a bean class:

```
    public class MyItem{
       public String getImageUrl(){
          if (isHttps){
            //return https url 
          }
      //return http url;
       }
    }
```

I can do this using ThreadLocal, but I would like to avoid taking that route.

Comment: What sort of request?  An `HttpServletRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative:

You can get the current request as follows:

```
    ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest req = sra.getRequest();
```

This uses thread-local under the covers.

If you are using Spring MVC that's all you need.   If you are not using Spring MVC then you will need to register a [RequestContextListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html) or [RequestContextFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) in your `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a request-scoped bean

```
<bean id="requestBean" class="com.foo.RequestBean" scope="request"/>
```

Then in that class, autowire the request (reference [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?59372-Accessing-HttpServletRequest-inside-a-request-scoped-bean)):

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Add a method in RequestBean that determines if the request is HTTPS.

```
public boolean isHttp() { // ... }
```

Then inject requestBean into your other beans that need to call isHttp().

Comment: Can we autowire a class into a bean which is not created by Spring.  For example, MyItem can be created from multiple classes, and I can't always pass in this requestBean when I create the MyItem class.

Comment: Yes, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring.

Comment: I posted another solution which is preferable.

Comment: Unfortunately, both solutions regarding autowiring a bean not created by Spring did not work.  Any other ideas?