# Preserving tabbed info in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is there a way to preserve the contents of a tabbed component when toggling between them? I found @PreserveOnRefresh but that only seems to work when refreshing the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean navigating between Routes/views rendered as tabs, I think what you're looking for is the @SpringComponent and @UIScope annotations. Add these to the relevant classes to preserve any input fields and outputs when toggling. Note that you'll still need @PreserveOnRefresh if you want to retain those fields when refreshing the page itself.

See: [Vaadin Component as Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005891/vaadin-component-as-spring-bean) for a breakdown of the specific functions the two annotations serve.