# If I use Spring's @Autowired annotation on a member of a class, can I new up the class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a dependent class `B` of class `A` that I want injected into `A`.

And so I use the `@Autowired` annotation in class `A`. But class `A` itself I create using `new` keyword and I find that the reference to class `B` is `null`.

So if you are using `Autowired`, must Spring manage class `A` also?

I mean, is the `null` reference because I am using `new` and not letting Spring manage the whole thing?

Comment: You are correct. Spring needs to bootstrap the entire application - if you use DI there should not be a single `new` anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the both classes need to be in the same context. Manage by Spring.

You can see an example here.
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring container should manage objects of class A and B to be able to inject B reference into A.