# How to inject dependencies when doing Object object = new Object()

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Is there a way to inject all the dependencies and sub-depencencies when I instantiate an object with the classic code `Object object = new Object()`?

As you can see from the code below, the class A autowires the class B, the class B autowires the class C.

When I instantiate the class A this way  `A a = new A();` of course the class A doens't have its dependencies B, and B doens't have its and so on.

Following this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_beanfactory_container.htm) I'm able to load the dependencies of A (so B is loaded inside A), but not the relative dependencies of B.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you

```
public class Start{
    public void start(){
       A a = new A();
    }
}

public class A{
    @Autowired B b;
}

public class B{
   @Autowired C c;
}

public class C{   
}
```

Comment: No. The Java language does not allow you to "hook" into the object creation mechanism. (There's nothing like overloading `new` like in C++.) `new` will allocate an object and invoke the constructor, that's all. No dependency injection framework can do magic.

Comment: Looks like an duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the spring engine that creates an object and put the created instance in a field annotated with `@Autowired`.

If an object is not under the control of the spring engine no `@Autowired` field is instantied.

So you can't have a field correctly initialized if you create the container object explicitly with a `new` (so if it is not under the control of spring engine).