# Can I process POJO by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, pojo

Suppose I have a POJO instance, which is annotated by `@Autowired`.

```
public class MyClass {
   @Autowired
   private Database database;
}
```

Can I invoke Spring processing for this instance programmatically, i.e. set `database` field from beans in the given context?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done manually for POJO's.

Autowire `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` in the caller class

```
@Autowired
AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
```

In the function where this class needs to be used.

```
MyClass a = new MyClass().
beanFactory.autowireBean(a);
```

This will update all spring dependencies in the object a, including the database autowiring.

This is similar to [How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can given a Spring ApplicationContext you should be able to call autowireBean() or configureBean() with the suitable parameters.