# Autowiring for spring unmanaged object

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to know how to Autowire sprig beans in java object that are not managed by spring application context.
I have created an instance of a class and but the subsequent autowiring objects are null. for eg.

```
@Service
Class BaseFactory {
public BaseObject getObject(String type ){
    BaseObject object = null; 
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("order")){
       object = new FirstServiceObject();
    }
   else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("payment")){
      object = new SecondServiceObject();
    }
  return object;
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class FirstServiceObject{

@Autowired
UserRepository mUserRepository;// coming as null

@Autowired
UserHelper userHelper;//coming as null

public getDownloadedData(String userName, String b){
   User user = userHelper.findUser(userName); //null pointer exception
}
```

}

My helper Class from where I am calling the above .

```
public class SomeHelper {

@Autowired
BaseFactory baseFactory;

public processUser(){
 BaseObject object = baseFactory.getObject("order");
 object.getDownloadedData("sunil","someString")
}
```

All the Autowired beans a coming as null inside FirstServiceObject

I have checked with all possible solution given already and none seems to be working for me.

Comment: did you annotate your BaseFactory with @component?

Comment: Why are you even using a factory, that only complicates things. Why not simply inject the services directly into the classes that need it? Nonetheless, let Spring manage the services, don't create instances yourself.

Comment: @Asterisk Yeah I Tried that also , it didn't work for me.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have  different use case as the response for objects returned through Factory invokes different method class at run time . here is my interface public interface DownloadResponse {
    List<?> getDownloadData(String username,String startDate);
}

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3813725/3315474)

Comment: Thanks guys ,It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer given in the following post solved the issue.
[How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)
This is what I have done

```
public class SomeHelper {

  @Autowired
  BaseFactory baseFactory;

  @Autowired
  AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  public processUser(){
    BaseObject object = baseFactory.getObject("order");
    beanFactory.autowireBean(object);
    object.getDownloadedData("sunil","someString");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can't

If you want to Autowired spring beans in your class, the class needs to be managed by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

If you application is using web context, then try this

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```