# Why spring automatically @Autowitred fields in non-managed classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

As far as I know spring provides some ways to inject beans into non-managed classes.
It can be done explicitly with AutowireCapableBeanFactory. ([How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring))

But I've faced strange (IMHO) behavior, when spring performs such injection automatically.

Here is an example with spring batch,

Configuration:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration 
public class ProcessorJobConfig {

//.....

@Bean(name = "pullRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate createPullRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();

    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean(name = "step")
public Step step(@Autowired ItemReader<Measurement> itemReader,
                 @Autowired ItemProcessor<Measurement, Event> itemProcessor,
                 @Autowired ItemWriter<Event> itemWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<Measurement, Event>chunk(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .reader(itemReader)
            .processor(itemProcessor)
            .writer(itemWriter)
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "restProcessorJob")
public Job job(@Qualifier("step") Step step) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("restProcessorJob")
            .start(step)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ItemReader<Measurement> itemReader() {
    RestMeasureReader restMeasureReader = new RestMeasureReader(); // Use new() explicitly
    return restMeasureReader;
}

//.....
}
```

Reader:

```
public class RestMeasureReader implements ItemReader<Measurement> {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestMeasureReader.class);

/**
 * NOTE: This field will be injected automatically by spring, even we are using new() to create instance of this class.
 */
@Autowired
@Qualifier("pullRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Override
public Measurement read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    // do some stuff
}
}
```

And application itself

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTask
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestAutowiredTaskApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestAutowiredTaskApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Even I use explicit new() to instantiate RestMeasureReader, its RestTemplate field will be injected afterwards.
Is it normal behavior? I do not expect spring to automatically inject fields when creating object with new().

Comment: You are creating a new instance of a class inside a method annotated with the spring `@Bean` annotation... Which makes it a spring managed bean. It would be true if you remove the `@Bean` annotation as then it isn't a spring managed bean. I suggest a read of the reference guide especially the section on java based configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about using `new` inside of your `@Configuration` class, then yes it is normal behavior. This is you Spring java configs. So it's is Spring managed context. You are not going to call `itemReader()` in your code explicitly.
So, when you are going to do this:

```
@Autowired
private ItemReader<Measurement> iterReader;
```

you will get instance of your `RestMeasureReader` from Spring's IoC.

But if you will try to do explicitly call `new RestMesureReader()` inside of your code, you will get a new instance of `RestMesureReader` not a Spring Proxy with injected `@Autowired` fields.

Try to remove `@Bean` from your `itemReader()` method declaration and won't event be able to autowire `RestMesureReader`.

So basically `@Configuration` classes are just a Spring configuration, not a real java code. Even though you call `new` Spring will still return you a proxy class.

For more information check [this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/).

Answer (score 1):

Spring processes beans returned by methods that are annotated with `@Bean` 
This allows you to use autowiring or livecycle callbacks when using Java configuration.

A more minimalistic example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public A a() {
    return new A();
  }

  static class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onPostConstruct() {
      System.out.println("postConstruct: " + b);
    }
  }

  @Component
  static class B {
  }
}
```

Here, even if the bean named `a` is created manually, Spring will inject dependencies (`b`) and call `@PostConstruct` callbacks.