# Spring boot @Autowired repository instance null when using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

**My situation is this:**

I am building a spring boot application, when I autowire the UserRepository in the controller it initializes it and when I try to call the findByUserName method everything is OK.

**UserController**

```
@Controller    
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/users") 
public class UserController {

@Autowired 
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping(path="/{userName}")
public @ResponseBody AuthenticationDetails getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String userName) throws UserNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);=
    ...
    }
}
```

After creating the controller I needed to use Spring Security to secure the paths of the controller so I added in the SecurityConfig class the following configuration:

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
...
}
```

Now, when I try to post a request to the /login path I get a NullPointerException in the CustomAuthenticationProvider class when I try to load the data through userRepository instance by calling the findByUserName method because userRepository instance is null.

**CustomAuthenticationProvider**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired 
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    User userFromRepository = userRepository.findByUserName(authentication.getName().toLowerCase()); 
    ...
}
```

**My questions are this:**

Is not the state of the beans the same during the run-time of the application? Are the beans created when the application loads right?

**Why Spring Boot manages to autowire the instance with the bean in my controller and in the same application but in another class it does not autowire them?**

Comment: Please show your code of the userRepository.
It is almost sure that you are missing @Repository annotation there, so Spring does not have a bean to autowire

Comment: As I said initially it works when I autowire it in my controller so the @Repository annotation is present

Comment: Can you share the code where you create your `CustomAuthenticationProvider`?

Comment: '@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByUserName(String username);
    
}'

Comment: Hi @Leffchik, you want the entire class? I have already posted the relevant code in my initial post on top.

Comment: It's just I think maybe you create it like `new CustomAuthenticationProvider()` so it's not a spring bean and not being managed by spring context. In this case, obviously, `@Autowire` wont work

Comment: You have to add `@Component` on your CustomAuthenticationProvider and beans will be injected. Please check also that package of `CustomAuthenticationProvider` in subpackage of package where is your class with annotation `@SpringBootApplication` and if this package with `ComponentScan` annotation.

Comment: @Autowired
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws
  Exception{
  auth.authenticationProvider(**new CustomAuthenticationProvider()**);
  }

You think this is the problem?

Comment: Yes! It is the problem. I had exactly the same issue.
Autowired is not working when you create instance using new

Comment: Definitely. This wont work. Your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` should be a spring bean, so it's fileds can be injected

Comment: OK, thank you for your replies. Kind regards

Comment: @Leffchik reply as an answer, not as a comment, so that I can mark it as correct if you want. Thank you.

Comment: @ArberHoxha, done. You're welcome.

Comment: you can return a `new` thing from a `@Bean` method within a `@Configuration` class and it will gets all the things injected, but otherwise, don't `new` things yourself. In very few very special cases you can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813725/995891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you create your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` like this `new CustomAuthenticationProvider()`, so it's not really a spring bean and it's fields can not be injected. What you need to do is define `CustomAuthenticationProvider` bean and it will work.