# @Autowired service is null but I need create new instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, autowired, runnable

I'm developing an app with Spring boot, I'm using the MVC model.
I have an entity called A, which has its controller, service and repository. all right up here.

I have an utility class, which is runnable and is called when the server start. This utility class create a set of A entities, and then, stored it into database. The problem is that the `autowired` service of the class is null, because I have created a new instance of the utility class in order to run it, so Spring doesn't create the autowired service correctly.

that is:

**Main.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    Runnable task = new Utility();
    ...
}
}
```

**Utility.java**

```
@Autowired
private Service service;
...
public void run() {
   ...
   service.save(entities);      <-- NPE
}
```

I know that Spring cannot autowired the service of this new instance, but I need to create the utility instance in order to run it.

I have tried to access to the service through application context, but the problem is the same:

```
 @Autowired 
 private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

I have tried to make runnable the controller (where the service is autowired correctly), but the problem is the same, since I need to do the `new controller();`.

I have read these posts
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)
[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418516/how-to-make-autowire-work-in-spring-when-creating-instance-manually), but any solution works.

UPDATE: I need that the task run in a new thread, since it will be executed each X hours. The task downloads a data set from Internet and save it into database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't simply create a `@Bean` for the utility class, and then call it inside the `@PostConstruct`?

Comment: Is Main.java your class with your main() method?

Comment: `autowiring` in Spring can be done in three ways, `contractor`, `method` and `field`, none matches in your case. Also, make sure you extend to an interface, else it will be `null`

Comment: I have updated the post to add extra information.

Comment: @tovarichML  "executed each X hours" Sounds like you're looking for a scheduler? https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino, That works! I love you so much right now. If you wish, reply it and I close the post with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do some task periodically:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}

@Component
class Runner {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?") // execute every 2 hours
    public void run() {
        // put your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to populate your database with dummy data.

> This utility class create a set of A entities, and then, stored it
>   into database

Why are you using a `Runnable`? Is this task run via a new `Thread`? 
If not, then use `@PostConstruct` inside your `@Controller`, which has access to the right `@Service`. The marked method is guaranteed to be invoked after the Bean has been completely constructed, and all its dependencies have been satisfied.

```
@PostConstruct
private void persistEntities() {
   ...
   service.save(entities);
}
```

---

If you're on Spring Boot, you can just place a `data-*.sql` file under `src/main/resources/`. It will be run at startup.

Comment: The task run via a new Thread. I'm downloading each X hours a data set from Internet and saves it into database. The process must be transparent to the final web user.

Answer (score 0):

Just as said @CoderinoJavarino in comments, I need to use `@Scheduled` instance of a runnable class.

With scheduled, Spring can autowired correctly the service. So, finally, my initial runnable utility class has become into a scheduled class.