# Print non-managed Spring bean name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created one simple SpringBoot Application.
There are two classes :

1) ManagedBean class

```
@Component
class ManagedBean
{
    public void fn()
    {
        System.out.println("B doin nothing");
    }
}
```

2) NonmangedBean : It has dependency of ManagedBean class

```
class NonmangedBean
{
    @Autowired
    ManagedBean mb;

    public void fn()
    {
        mb.fn();
        System.out.println("doin nothing");
    }
}
```

There is third Service class which has Rest End points.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class Service
{
    @Autowired 
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @GetMapping("/getBeanNames")
    public List<String> printBeans() 
    {
        return Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames());
    }

    @GetMapping("/processBean")
    public String processBean()
    {
        NonmangedBean nb = new NonmangedBean();
        beanFactory.autowireBean(nb);
        nb.fn();

        return "Success";
    }
}
```

First I am calling /processBean endpoint which will crete Object of NonmangedBean class and autowires it.
(Here my understading it that bean will live in Spring Container till i shutdown the server.)

After that I hit /getBeanNames endpoint to get all the bean names in Spring Container but I didn't find NonmangedBean in the list. I find ManagedBean in that list.

Questions :

1) Will this type of(NonmangedBean) autowired beans be stored in Spring Container?
2) Will this type of autowired beans die as soon as request process completed?
3) Am I doing anything wrong in printBeans method? Should I use anything else than applicationContext to get SpringBean lists?
Open for your suggetions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here my understading it that bean will live in Spring Container till i
>   shutdown the server

Your understanding is wrong it will die with the request i.e. the scope of the object is within that method(`processBean`) only. The container will **NOT** manage your bean. Apart from that, there is no sense in using

`@Autowired` in your non managed bean. Since container doenn't manage it it will be null (unless you inject it using `beanFactory.autowireBean();`) and therefore answer to your question that if you can print any such bean using spring services is NO

Comment: My @Autowired bean has value(NOT NULL) as I have registered using AutowireCapableBeanFactory. You may refer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring

Comment: My bad i missed `beanFactory.autowireBean(nb);` Updated the same

Comment: @Pratiksoni But the answer to your question has more to do with the lifecycle of the request and I hope that answers your question

Comment: Yes, That answers my questions. Thanks Yati.