# Cannot get @Value from inside an instance or bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a property set to "true", that I want to bind to my checkStatus field.

```
@Value("${prop.checkstatus}")
private boolean checkStatus;
```

I am able to access the value from inside an @Service class.  However, if I use @Value inside a class that I instantiate or retrieve using AppliationContext.getBean("classA"), the value is always "false" since it cannot get the correct value from the property file.  Please advise as I need to access this value from an instance and from a bean.

In some parts of the code, I create the object using new and try to access @Value.  I understand that this is not possible since the new object is not managed by spring.  But there are parts of the code where the object is retrieved using applicationcontext.  Still I cannot access the @Value.  Is there a better approach in retrieving @Value both for objects created using new and applicationcontext.getbean?

Comment: Do you use Spring-Boot? How is the class using this property configured?

Comment: use `application.properties`

Comment: I am using properties file.  Otherwise, I won't be getting the value from within my service class.  I don't use spring-boot.

Comment: It will not be in the class you instantiate because that instance will not be managed by spring. For `AppliationContext.getBean("classA")` we need to see your spring config and how you get the `AppliationContext`.

Comment: *if I use @Value inside a class that I instantiate or retrieve using AppliationContext.getBean("classA")* - you always have to use application context. Creating with `new` wont work.

Comment: I just inject the ApplicationContext
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

Comment: I edited the question with the last paragraph

Comment: For completeness - Spring has supported for a little while the notion of @Configurable classes, for which it will do dependency injection when instances are allocated through plain new expressions.  But this is recommended only when one cannot control instantiation (like Servlets) - otherwise, getting beans from appContext would be best/easiest...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)

Comment: if I go with the Configurable, will Value also works? I see in the answer that it is so that Autowired will work inside the new instance. I'm not sure if I use the other approach of AutowireCapableBean that i will still have a different instance everytime I do new(). Also how to solve the ApplicationContext.getBean("classA"), is it the same that I annotate classA with Configurable?