# Call init method after object initialization and autowiring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a class as follows:

```
class FooBar {
    @Autowired
    SomeObj someObj;

    FooBar() {
        // Cant call this here as someObj is not yet initialized
        // someObj.someMethod();
    }

    private void init() {
        someObj.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I'm creating the object of fooBar as follows:

```
FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
```

How can I automatically call `init` after creation and autowiring are complete?

Comment: use `@PostConstruct` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct

Comment: Autowiring does not even work this way. If you let _Spring_ handle the instantiation you can use `@PostConstruct` to perform your intialization.

Comment: @diginoise @ trylimits that doesn't work when instantiating objects using new.

Comment: @ayushgp that's why I stated, that also `@Autowiring` doesn't work if you instantiate using `new`. Therefore there's no way to get `init` called _after_ autowiring is complete, because that just never happens. You have to use the _Spring_ way to create your object or process your created instance via a `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`.

Comment: There is a way to inject dependencies into object created via constructor. Check answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring. However this is a bad hack and if you have to do so you really need to rethink your architecture