# How to inject JpaRepository to not service class

Tags: spring

I have interface like this

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

In class adnotated @RestController Spring is able to wired with proper field.

But how can I do this if I want to create class without any adnotation in spring? I have to create implementation of this repository? If yes, can I do it like spring is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)

Comment: why you need that for? unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

Inject

`private final ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext;`

into the class instantiating your desired class. Then call:

`YourClass yourClass = (YourClass) configurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().initializeBean(new YourClass(), "YourClassName");`

yourClass will then hold an instance of YourClass which has been initialized as if it was a Spring `@Component` (or a `@RestController`, which is the same from the dependency-injection point of view).

Answer (score -1):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext appContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrawlerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.appContext = applicationContext;
    }
```

....

```
MainApplication.getAppContext().getBean(CarRepository.class)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are of low quality. Please try to add an explanation.