# The class is missing @Component. How do I autowire this class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, dependencies

Usually, we use `@Componenet` right? and also specialized forms `@Controller`, and `@Service` for particular classes. So those annotations are responsible to create beans during the spring app creation, correct?

My current problem is I have a particular dependency. Inside that dependency, it is `@Autowire` another class, let's say `classB`. But that `classB` doesn't have any class-level annotation such as `@Compoenent`.

ex.

```
public class classA {
  @Autowired
  private ClassB classB;
}

public class classB {
 // logic....
}
```

So when I try to run the app, I get an error something like this -- please ignore the class name and package name..

```
Field demoService in com.example.demo.controller.DemoController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.DemoService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
   - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

And like I said before, those are from dependency jar so I can't really edit, they are read-only file.

I am thinking about to have config class like below

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public DemoService myDemoService(){
        return new DemoService();
    }
```

I am not sure if it's going to work or not.

Do you have different ideas?

Thank you for reading my question

I haven't tried the config class. Looking for other people's ideas, experience , how to resolve this

Comment: "@Componenet" looks like [a misspelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/component#Noun). Is it?

Comment: for defining beans from dependencies config class is the recommended approach since we can avoid the component scans in the dependency jars

Comment: you can extend the DemoService base class and define a new class and make it @Compenent

Answer (score 3):

The creation of the DemoService Bean in the configuration class is the right approach. There are two ways you can create a bean in Spring, one by adding the @Component annotation and allowing spring to create the object or by specifying the bean in the configuration class.

There is however another way to achieve this. This is documented in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring). Essentially, you create an initiation of the DemoService and auto wire dynamically in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Creating config class would also work correctly. If you don't want to create a new class, define that bean inside application class i.e where you're using **@SpringBootApplication** annotation or from where you're running the application.